# limit data returned by sys.settrace()

Tags: python, trace

In the code example below, I get all the trace data I want (tracing the local values of the `permute()` function), but then I get some unwanted data, starting with:

```
('call', 406, {})
('line', 407, {})
('call', 986, {'name': 'atexit', 'import_': <built-in function __import__>})
```

and culminating with an error:

```
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 117, in __repr__
AttributeError: '_ModuleLock' object has no attribute 'name'
```

How can I limit the output to just the function variables please? In Python 2 the extra output was not produced. I'm using Python 3.8.

```
import sys

def trace(frame, event, arg_unused):
    print((event, frame.f_lineno, frame.f_locals))
    return trace

sys.settrace(trace)

def permute(A, P):
    n = len(A)

    # For each element of P
    for i in range(n):
        next = i

        # Check if it is already
        # considered in cycle
        while (P[next] >= 0):

            # Swap the current element according
            # to the permutation in P
            t = A[i]
            A[i] = A[P[next]]
            A[P[next]] = t

            temp = P[next]

            # Subtract n from an entry in P
            # to make it negative which indicates
            # the corresponding move
            # has been performed
            P[next] -= n
            next = temp


if __name__ == '__main__':
    A = [5, 6, 7, 8]
    P = [3, 2, 1, 0]

    permute(A, P)
    print(A)
```

Answer (score 1):

I was a small thing, but significant: it turns out I needed to add `sys.settrace(None)` after the function call to avoid the unwanted output.