# Starting Python tracing at arbitrary position in (middle of) code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider the following code, `test.py`:

```py
import sys, os
import time
import urllib.request


with urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.example.com/') as f:
    html = f.read().decode('utf-8')

print("A: {}".format(time.time()))

time.sleep(2)

print("B: {}".format(time.time()))
```

If I run this as usual, I get output like this:

```
$ python3 test.py
A: 1634285044.6374931
B: 1634285046.6485002
```

Now, let's say I want to trace the code - starting right before the `time.sleep(2)` statement. I do not know how that is done, however a typical "tracing" can be started on the command line, like so:

```
$ python3 -m trace --trace test.py
 --- modulename: test, funcname: <module>
test.py(1): import sys, os
test.py(2): import time
test.py(3): import urllib.request
 --- modulename: _bootstrap, funcname: _find_and_load
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1004):  --- modulename: _bootstrap, funcname: __init__
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>(153): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(154):  --- modulename: _bootstrap, funcname: __enter__
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>(157):  --- modulename: _bootstrap, funcname: _get_module_lock
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>(172): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(173): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(174): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(175): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(176): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(177): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(179): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(180): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(183):  --- modulename: _bootstrap, funcname: __init__
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>(59): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(60): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(61): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(62): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(63): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(64): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(185): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(196): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(198): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(200): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(158):  --- modulename: _bootstrap, funcname: acquire
...
```

... but the output - at least for the imports and the `urlopen()` - is MASSIVE, and it makes it *extremely* difficult to see what is going on!

Btw, if you comment the `import urllib.request` and the `with urllib.request.urlopen ...` lines, the trace is just this:

```
$ python3 -m trace --trace test.py
 --- modulename: test, funcname: <module>
test.py(1): import sys, os
test.py(2): import time
test.py(9): print("A: {}".format(time.time()))
A: 1634285323.556725
test.py(11): time.sleep(2)
test.py(13): print("B: {}".format(time.time()))
B: 1634285325.5598364
test.py(775): """
```

So, ideally I would a facility, that would allow me to start the trace in the middle of (or rather, at arbitrary position in) the code; something like this pseudocode example:

```
import sys, os
import time
import urllib.request


with urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.example.com/') as f:
    html = f.read().decode('utf-8')

print("A: {}".format(time.time()))


# I'd want the line-by-line tracing to start here; so:
import trace; trace.START_TRACE()

time.sleep(2)

print("B: {}".format(time.time()))
```

Is there a facility for doing this in Python 3?

Comment: You might have more luck with the [filter options](https://docs.python.org/3/library/trace.html#filters).

Comment: Thanks @user2357112supportsMonica - since the above example is just a stand in for a much more complex code, filters would be difficult to utilize ... However, I looked a bit further, and found some posts also with your answers, and found how I can just use a custom `sys.settrace` to achieve what I want - see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, so after the comment by @user2357112supportsMonica, I looked into the source of the `trace` module [cpython/trace.py at 3.10 · python/cpython](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/trace.py) - and I could see, that it basically compiles the script code (which is why intervention in the middle of it would be tricky) - but, it also uses `sys.settrace`.

So, I looked a bit more, and found examples of how you can make a custom tracer function for `sys.settrace` - and with that, the OP example can be modified as:

```py
import sys, linecache                   # add
# mytrace function based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63927342/limit-data-returned-by-sys-settrace
def mytrace(frame, event, arg_unused):  # add
    filename = frame.f_code.co_filename
    lineno = frame.f_lineno
    print((event, filename, lineno, linecache.getline(filename, lineno)) ) # frame.f_locals
    return mytrace

import sys, os
import time
import urllib.request


with urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.example.com/') as f:
    html = f.read().decode('utf-8')

# START TRACING
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65350552/sys-settrace-seems-to-be-ignored-in-threads
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55998616/how-to-trace-code-run-in-global-scope-using-sys-settrace
sys._getframe().f_trace = mytrace
sys.settrace(mytrace)

print("A: {}".format(time.time()))

time.sleep(2)

# STOP TRACING
sys.settrace(None)

print("B: {}".format(time.time()))
```

And then, when you run this code:

```
$ python3 test.py
('line', '/tmp/test.py', 23, 'print("A: {}".format(time.time()))\n')
A: 1634290271.2226915
('line', '/tmp/test.py', 25, 'time.sleep(2)\n')
('line', '/tmp/test.py', 28, 'sys.settrace(None)\n')
B: 1634290273.228311
```

Nice - exactly what I wanted!